# Share one monitor with another user and display their screen as well

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

My housemate and I just started playing the original RollerCoaster Tycoon again - what a nostalgia trip! Anyways, we both have two monitors, and would like to view the other's game on the secondary monitor while playing, since we're in different rooms.

VNC-like applications sorta work, but they require two separate instances running (one to share each direction), and as a whole are rather slow and clumsy. We don't need any remote control at all, just viewing.

I'm using XP, he Windows 7. We could probably get it to run through some means in Linux, if necessary.

Comment: How far are the rooms apart physically? What outputs do your graphics cards have, and what inputs do your monitors have?

Comment: The rooms are kitty-corner; our computers are roughly 20 feet apart.  My video card outputs VGA and DVI; both my monitors are VGA (I use an adapter).  I believe my housemate uses DVI for both his monitors, with no adapters.